# Magento Model is not Working

Tags: magento

I am following this tutorial 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics.

As per this tutorial,when i pass a value with url like(http://localhost/dev/weblog/index/testModel/id/1), I am getting error like this

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in app\code\local\Srivats\Weblog\controllers\IndexController.php on line 10
```

This is my index controller code

```
<?php
class Srivats_Weblog_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function testModelAction()
    {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $blogpost = Mage::getModel('weblog/blogpost');
        echo("Loading the blogpost with an ID of ".$params['id']);
        $blogpost->load($params['id']);
        $data = $blogpost->getData();
        var_dump($data);
    }
}
```

Blogpost.php file

```
<?php
class Srivats_Weblog_Model_Mysql4_Blogpost extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('weblog/blogpost','blogpost_id');
    }
}
```

Here is my config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <config>
            <global>
                <modules>
                    <srivats_weblog>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                    </srivats_weblog>
                </modules>
                <models>
                    <weblog_mysql4>
                        <class>Srivats_Weblog_Model_Mysql4</class>
                        <resourceModel>weblog_mysql4</resourceModel>
                    </weblog_mysql4>
                </models>
            </global>
            <frontend>
                <routers>
                    <weblog>
                        <use>standard</use>
                        <args>
                            <module>Srivats_Weblog</module>
                            <frontName>weblog</frontName>
                        </args>
                    </weblog>
                </routers>
            </frontend>
        </config>
```

system.log shows

> Warning: include() [function.include]:
>   Failed opening 'Mage\Weblog\Model\Blogpost.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='app\code\local;E:\dev\app\code\community;app\code\core;E:\dev\lib;.;C:\php\pear')
>   in lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93

Here is the link to all files https://gist.github.com/cf99e4277599954f38d4 
I think this line `$blogpost->load($params['id']);` causing trouble.What i am missing.Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh in you config you should have

```
<global>
    <models>
        <weblog>
            <class>Srivats_Weblog_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>weblog_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </weblog>
    </model>
</global>
```

you already have for mysql4 resource add this on top of that. You should have

```
            <models>
                <weblog>
                  <class>Srivats_Weblog_Model</class>
                  <resourceModel>weblog_mysql4</resourceModel>
                </weblog>
                <weblog_mysql4>
                    <class>Srivats_Weblog_Model_Mysql4</class>
                </weblog_mysql4>
            </models>
```

Comment: @Nasaralla: Your answer is really helpful.But still same error.I have uploaded files for your reference.

Comment: @Alan Storm: nope :) the class reference for weblog node should not include '_Blogpost'. Also, there is no need to specify a resourceModel in the resource model node (weblog_mysql4).

Comment: oh yeah my bad... it should be 'Srivats_Weblog_Model'

Comment: @Nasaralla: I came close.But still there is error.`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Srivats_Weblog_Model_Mysql4_Blogpost::getData() in app\code\local\Srivats\Weblog\controllers\IndexController.php on line 13.`You can see files link in question

Comment: in order to do a get data on resource you would need to create a collection, i.e. add a folder Srivats/Weblog/Model/Mysql4/Blogpost and add Collection.php inside it. The collection signature should be Srivats_Weblog_Model_Mysql4_Blogpost_Collection and the _construct will have $this->_init('weblog/blogpost'); Then on your controller you do Mage::getResourceModel('weblog/blogpost_collection');

Answer (score 0):

Your real problem is that the line:

```
$blogpost = Mage::getModel('weblog/blogpost');
```

Is not returning an object and so $blogpost is just NULL.

Is the blogpost model class file actually created in `app/code/local/Srivats/Weblog/Model/Blogpost.php`

Comment: @Simon the way his is trying to load the model would require the file located in the path I specified. The config in turn specifies a resource model with should be loaded using Mage::getResourceModel() ... and yes one should be aware that paths are case sensitive.

Comment: @ElGabbu LOL yes, now that is right. But in your first version, the path was actually wrong...